# Should a child widget handle its' own events?

Tags: c++, user-interface, event-handling

I often come across a dilemma when implementing GUI. Suppose I have a simple widget hierarchy with a main window which has several child widgets. Should the child widgets handle events (arising, for example, from user input) themselves, or delegate handling to their parent widget? Here's a simple example: a window should close when its' close button is clicked. Who closes the window? Does the window react to the button event and close itself? Or does the button call the Close method on the window? The framework I'm using strongly hints that the preferred way is for child widgets to fire events to their parent widget, which should handle them as it sees fit, so the window would be close like this (in C++-ish pseudocode):

```
void ChildWidget::OnClick()
{
    GetParentWidget()->OnEvent(CreateClickEvent(*this));
}

void ParentWidget::OnEvent(Event& _event)
{
    if (_event.Type() == EventTypeClick && _event.Id() == "close_button")
    {
        Close();
    }
    else if ...
        ...
}
```

However, I'm afraid it breaks the single responsibility principle and leads to the parent widget doing too much work. I could instead give the child widgets the objects they need to handle their events, like:

```
class CloseButtonWidget : public Widget
{
public:
    CloseButtonWidget(Widget& widget_to_close)
    : WidgetToClose_(&widget_to_close)
    {}

    void OnClick()
    {
        WidgetToClose->Close();
    }       

private:
    Widget* WidgetToClose_;
};
```

The downside I can see is that in many cases I'll have to create a new class for such a self-handling widget, however, I often have to create new classes for child widgets anyway, so that is often not much of a problem.

Another way I can think of is to give the child widget a callback, like:

```
auto close_widget = new Widget();
// Suppose parent_widget is in scope
auto handler = CreateHandler(EventTypeClick, [parent_widget](){ parent_widget->Close(); }); 
close_widget->SetHandler(handler);
```

So the question is - what is the best place to handle the events coming from child widgets? What are the advantages and disadvantages for the ways described above? Maybe there are other, better ways to do this? I would be particularly interested in hearing any pros for the "parent widget handles everything" scenario, because I find it hard to see any.
I'd like to clarify that I would like an answer which addresses the question in a more "philosophical" way (like what would be better design), keeping with the preferred ways and quirks of the framework I'm using isn't very important.

Comment: I ended up going the callback way. I had to write a bunch of helper classes to compensate for our framework, and now life seems a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMPO the first method is a bottleneck. The OS/framework does a lot ob job to provide you widget-specific events, to avoid you have to do the "fetching" process. And you handles every event through a single event handler? Sounds like a ridiculous waste of time.

If you want to treat a set of events (Or the same event raised from a set of widgets) in the same manner, use the same event handler.

For example, a battleship-like game: You have a grid of buttons, and you handles the click event of all buttons of the grid in the same manner (The only difference between one button and other are its coordinates).

If you have to do different operations in every widget-event (Or in different events of the same widget), handle widget-specific events with its own handlers.

As you have noticed, the problem with specific handlers is their implementation. Makes you to overduplicate code. But think that you are not in Java! You have first-class functions (Through raw-function-pointers or functors), not pseudo-function-delegates (Aka inner classes) that fits 20 lines to write a single-line operation only. You are in C++, you have templates, lambdas, functors, and other useful tools to write specific handlers with only one simple and clear line of code :)

As you can see, I prefer to use your 3th way every time thats possible/simple.